# unable to install rjb1.4.9 on linux states that java_home is not set

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux

I am currently working on elementary os and am unable to bundle install on rails. The issue was being unable to install rjb 1.4.9. Though it says that Java_Home is not set, I can find it in the path.

```
$JAVA_HOME
bash: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/: Is a directory



Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rjb:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rjb-1.4.9/ext
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20161026-13902-19etf2h.rb extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details. You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)2.3
extconf.rb:53:in `<main>': JAVA_HOME is not set. (RuntimeError)

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rjb-1.4.9     for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/rjb-1.4.9/gem_make.out
```

Comment: is $JAVA_HOME >>exported<<?   Are you running the build in the same shell as the one where you printed $JAVA_HOME?

Comment: Yes I am running it in the same shell.

Comment: Did you export it?

Comment: Yes I did. I tried opening up a new shell and checking if the JAVA_HOME variable was still set and it was.

Answer (score 6):

Try a more direct aproach like:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64 gem install rjb
```

If you’re using csh/tcsh, you may have to use setenv instead.

Comment: thnx alot for the help